# Cross-Browser Opacity Javascript Properties

Tags: javascript, css

I just got done reading this article: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

This (misleading?) statement caught my eye:
"These days, you really don't have to worry about opacity being a difficult thing cross-browser. You just use the opacity property, like this:

```
.thing {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

"

**Is there no longer a use for:**

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

?

And also, why is it so hard to find Javascript property selectors for old browsers? All I was able to find was "MozOpacity" here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljdkioqd.php, and the "filter.alpha" property here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljqtwlbv.php. What about the khtml property selector? The statement in the article made seems to be misleading to me if there is still a use for these other selectors. He's making it seem like all of a sudden opacity works in every browser old and new. I just need some clarification (I've read every other question on StackOverflow regarding opacity cross-browser and have found nothing significant).

<----------------------------- UPDATE --------------------------------->

I've found all of the selectors! Here they are for anyone who wants to use them:

```
.style.opacity
.style.MsFilter
.style.filter.alpha
.style.MozOpacity
.style.KhtmlOpacity
```

Note: When using the "MsFilter" property:

```
.style.MsFilter = "\"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=1)\"";
```

Comment: In rare cases you might need to support IE8, the rest is long gone

Comment: So just to clarify... MozOpacity and khtmlOpacity are completely useless today and have no purpose whatsoever? Also, if I am trying to lower the opacity of an element with Javascript should I use document.getElementById("").style.filter.alpha and document.getElementById("").style.opacity to select the element's opacity for both browsers?

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("").style.opacity = ...`

Comment: Plus, I'd like to suggest that you should rely more on CSS these days, rather than tweaking element's properties in JavaScript, like opacity. Just try to avoid these situations as much as you can and let CSS handle that.

Comment: I entirely agree that you should use as little Javascript as possible to make your site work, but I made this simply as a fallback solution for CSS animate and @keyframe. The purpose of this for me, was so everything <IE10 can handle my animation, which includes elements changing opacity value over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He's making it seem like all of a sudden opacity works in every
>   browser old and new.

You can find browser usage stats here:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity

caniuse.com estimates a global user base of **0.63%** for IE8.

The other browsers (IE7 and lower, Netscape and Safari 1) are not listed.

Comment: So it comes down to how many people use it... So THERE IS a purpose for these property selectors, it just doesn't pertain to 99% of the population, correct?

Comment: Pretty much. We could all - in theory at least - try our best to gracefully degrade all the way back to NCSA Mosaic. But there's a real-world cut-off point when browser usage drops really low.

Comment: There's also a point where people using those browsers have bigger problems that opacity not working right on your site. IE8 doesn't even get security updates from Microsoft any longer.

Answer (score 1):

<----------------------------- UPDATE --------------------------------->

I've found all of the selectors! Here they are for anyone who wants to use them:

```
.style.opacity
.style.MsFilter
.style.filter.alpha
.style.MozOpacity
.style.KhtmlOpacity
```

Note: When using the "MsFilter" property make sure to cancel the extra set of quotes with a slash:

```
.style.MsFilter = "\"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=1)\"";
```

Thank you everyone for your help/input!